# Determine the number of simple 7-vertex, 4-regular graph that are pairwise non isomorphic.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm taking an introductory graph theory course and I am having trouble going about answering this question. I've been told to look at the graph compliment but I don't quite understand how that ties into this.

Comment: The complement (with an e, by the way) must be a 2-regular graph on 7 vertices.  Can you describe all 2-regular graphs?